# MIPS Issue implementing loop

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm trying to implement a loop in MIPS assembly but I'm having trouble doing so. I have commented my code with my attempt and logic at each step and the original question.

```
int a[20]; 
int b = 17;
while b < 22 do:{ 
    a[int(b / 2)] = b * 13; 
    b = b + 1 
}
```

```
.data
    a:      .space 80
    b_num:  .word  17

.text
    .globl main
    main:   la    $s0, a            # load base address of a into $s0
            lw    $s5, b_num        # load b into $s5

    Loop:   li $t3, 2           # load integer 2 into $t3
            li $t4, 13          # load integer 13 into $t4
            div $s5, $t3        # divide b by 2
            mflo $s3            # move quotient into $s3
            add $t1, $s3, $s3   # $t1 = 2*i
            add $t1, $t1, $t1   # $t1 = 4*i
            add $t1, $t1, $s0   # $t1 = address of a[i] , a[i] = a[b/2], added 
                                # base address of a with counter i which is b/2

            slti $s6, $s5, 22   # check if b < 22 and put a 1 or 0 into $s6
            bne  $s6, $zero, Exit # check if $s6 from previous inequality is 0 (False). If so, Exit program.
            mult $s5,$t4        # b * 13
            mflo $t5            # move answer to $t5
            sw  $t5, 0($t1)     # a[i] = $t5
            addi $s5, $s5, 1    # b = b + 1
            j   Loop

    Exit:
            li $v0, 10            # Get ready for a system call.
            syscall               # syscall number 10: End of program.
```

Comment: You haven't explained what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
 beqz $s6, Exit
```

instead of

```
 bne  $s6, $zero, Exit
```

If you leave it this way, then only one loop iteration is executed.